# google now integration on website for Websiteupdates in Google Now

Tags: schema, google-now, email-notifications

I am working on some integrations for Google Now.
The Schemas for Email-Notifications are clear,... 
But bow I am searching for integrating our Website-News as well.
(I always get "website update-cards from Ryanair on my GNow)
But I cant seem to find the right schemas for it,... I dont even know if it is done by schema-markup-micromarkup-whatever *lol*
Any help or idea?
Thank you lots
Greets
Ray

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have been wondering this same question for a while and these are what I have found.

1. Google Now doesn't support my PHP site but it does support another Drupal site of mine.
2. The only page that Google Now provides integration is here: https://www.google.com/landing/now/integrations.html
3. I found that quite some of the supported websites have rss.xml on its root.

So here's what I recommend to do: (I'm still trying so I'm not certain if the following methods are worth trying)

1. Use Drupal or other well-known CMS in case Google Now only supports a few kinds of websites.
2. Go to that page and try to get in contact with Google. (I haven't got replies yet though)
3. Try to add an rss.xml on your site's root and add a link to it at your default page. (I haven't got time to try it yet)